# Export Large Sparse Matrix As .mtx File

Tags: matrix, export, data

I'm trying to export a large sparse matrix of dimension 1164960 by 1164960 with 17815680 elements as an .mtx file so I can import it into Python. I first the run the following code successfully.

```
s1 = SparseArray[Uncompress[Import["Elements18.m"]]]
```

I then try to export s1 as a .mtx file.

```
Export["RandomGraphMat18.mtx", s1, "MTX"]
```

However it gives me this error message without an explanation.

Export::type: <<1>> cannot be exported to the MatrixMarket format. >>

$Failed

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can help me resolve this error.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, that is impossible to tell without knowing the matrix `s1`. Maybe you can boil it down to some small minimal example? Maybe `s1` contains symbolic entries?

Comment: It should contain only numbers as element. If this error can be caused by it containing a symbolic entries I'll check for that.

Comment: Of course it can be caused by symbols. To my knowledge, `MatrixMarket` is only meant for storing numerical matrices. An I think also only for those in double precision. So you should also try to apply `N` to `s1` before you export.